# Trying to install pygame on OSX 10.11 for python2

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pygame

I'm running OSX 10.11 and have python 2.7.10 installed on my computer. I want to install pygame1.9.2 for the said environment (don't want to install it for python3 which is installed on my computer as well).

When I try to install this one - http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip - it says, "This package is incompatible with this version of OS X and may fail to install." Even if I continue, installation fails somehow.

I tried "pip install pygame" then it says

> "Collecting pygame   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement pygame (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>   for pygame. "

How do I install it?

Answer (score 0):

(for future reference) After spending many hours I found the following command to be working!

```
sudo pip install --user  git+https://github.com/pygame/pygame/
```

It's not 1.9.2 but can run what I wanted with python 2.7.10

```
>>> pygame.__version__
'2.0.0.dev0'
```